# Multiple success callback_urls with Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Google?

Tags: angularjs, perl, google-oauth, dancer

Im using [Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Google](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Google) for openId login system.

I need to have a second `callback_url`.

Is this possible? If so, how is this done and how can I define when each url should be used?

In practice I have two different buttons on different sites that call and redirect to google login. One is the general login page that redirects on success to the given callback url(config.yml).

The second button is rendered in an angularjs modal window on server request after session expires. This is the scenario I need the second callback url for.

The idea is that when session has expired you would have the google login on a new tab in stead of redirecting from original window(to avoid refreshing page and loosing possibly uncommitted data) and on successful callback redirect to the alternative callback_url which would be a static page which closes itself on load and maybe even sets the focus(not sure will work on all browsers) back to the original window/tab which all along has not had to be refreshed and threfor wont delete un saved data of the forms it holds.

Right now my "config.yml" holds only:

```
plugins:
'Auth::Google':
    client_id:        'xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    client_secret:    'xxxx'
    scope:            'profile email'
    access_type:      'online'
    callback_url:     'http://localhost:3000/callback'
    callback_success: '/auth/orised/google'
    callback_fail:    '/auth/fail'
```

Comment: as long as you add them both in the Google developer console and have different code on each of the buttons this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank I'll revise the console options